# Find and FindOne in NestJS without FindOneOptions

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I tryed us find and findOne in NestJS. Currently I have this code and it works:

```
  findOne(id: number) {
    const options: FindOneOptions<User> = { where: { id } };
    return this.repo.findOne(options);
  }

  find(email: string) {
    const options: FindOneOptions<User> = { where: { email } };
    return this.repo.find(options);
  }
```

Problem is that tutorial which I'm doing doesn't use FindOneOption. It use only `this.repo.findOne` or `this.repo.find` but all the time I had an error. Which is the best way to do that? Could I'm not using `FindOneOptions`?